# Jenkins marks build as success instead of unstable

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ant

I use Jenkins 2. There is a job where Jenkins has to log to a remote server with SSH and execute a simple command.
The SSH connection fails but Jenkins still marks the build as success.

I resolved the issue with the SSH connection but I am worried Jenkins will mark other builds as success even when there are errors. Is there a way to mark the job as unstable in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins can sometimes skip errors and mark builds as success. You can install the  [Log Parser](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser) plugin. That way, you will have more control over what Jenkins can treat as failure and what it can ignore.

After installing, create your own rule that tells what the log parser needs to look for in console output. Once you have the rules in place, Jenkins will mark the build as a failure if the keyword appears in the logs in the future.

Another alternative is [Build Failure Analyzer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-failure-analyzer). The documentation is pretty good and walks you through how you can setup and define rules for failures.